# How to add gap and text between path in d3.js?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, svg, d3.js

I have created a line chart using d3.js, now I want to add the gap and text between the path.

[live demo](http://jsfiddle.net/jtkqax91/1/)

What I have so far.

HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>D3 Stacked Bar and Line Chart</title>
    <script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v5.min.js"></script>
  </head>
  <style>
    .dot {
  display: none;
}

.line-segment {
  fill: none;
  stroke: steelblue;
  stroke-width: 2;
}

.line-text {
  font-size: 12px;
  font-weight: bold;
}
  </style>
  <body>
    <div id="main-chart">
        <svg width="960" height="500"></svg>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

JS

```
const data = [
  { year: "2015", value: 120 },
  { year: "2016", value: 200 },
  { year: "2017", value: 300 },
  { year: "2018", value: 400 },
  { year: "2019", value: 500 }
];

const margin = { top: 20, right: 20, bottom: 30, left: 50 };
const width = 600 - margin.left - margin.right;
const height = 400 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

const svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
  .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
  .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
  .append("g")
  .attr("transform", `translate(${margin.left},${margin.top})`);

const xScale = d3.scaleBand()
  .range([0, width])
  .domain(data.map(d => d.year))
  .padding(0.2);

const yScale = d3.scaleLinear()
  .range([height, 0])
  .domain([0, d3.max(data, d => d.value)]);

const line = d3.line()
  .x(d => xScale(d.year) + xScale.bandwidth() / 2)
  .y(d => yScale(d.value))
  .defined(function(d) {return !isNaN(d)});

svg.append("g")
  .attr("transform", `translate(0, ${height})`)
  .call(d3.axisBottom(xScale));

svg.append("g")
  .call(d3.axisLeft(yScale));

  svg.selectAll(".line-segment")
  .data(data.slice(0, -1))
  .enter().append("path")
  .attr("class", "line-segment")
  .attr("d", d => {
    const x1 = xScale(d.year) + xScale.bandwidth() / 2;
    const x2 = xScale(data[data.indexOf(d) + 1].year) + xScale.bandwidth() / 2;
    const y1 = yScale(d.value);
    const y2 = yScale(data[data.indexOf(d) + 1].value);
    return `M${x1},${y1} L${x2},${y2}`;
  })
  .attr("stroke", "steelblue")
  .attr("stroke-width", 2);


svg.selectAll(".line-text")
  .data(data)
  .enter().append("text")
  .attr("class", "line-text")
  .text(d => d.value)
  .attr("x", d => xScale(d.year) + xScale.bandwidth() / 2)
  .attr("y", d => yScale(d.value) - 0)
  .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
  .attr("font-size", "12px");
```

**The above solution gives me the following**
[image]

**But the expected result should be something like this**

[image]

Comment: You do not need to split the path into segments. Just make a single path and then put the text with some background on top.

If you think the accepted answer is not enough and you want a solution that adapts your own code, let me know and I will add one.

Comment: @wasserholz please add your solution, the accepted answer is a little bit complicated, my end goal is to have multiple line charts with gaps and text plus stacked bar charts on the same chart

Comment: I see now, why you used scaleBand for the x axis. You want to put a bar chart on top and that usually uses ordinal scales. But scaleBand does not work well together with paths. Overall your current solution for generating paths is a good tradeoff. Another solution would be to use scaleLinear and tweak it a bit. Otherwise handling zooming will be a real pain. I usually use linear scales for that as they work smoothly with interpolations and can easily reflect ordinal domains.

Comment: please accept an answer to give out the bounty otherwise the bounty will expire in 13 hours.

Answer (score 2):

[This example](https://observablehq.com/@d3/inline-labels) from the [D3 Gallery](https://observablehq.com/@d3/gallery) does what you are looking for. Note that the implementation does not split the path and adds gaps and text in between, but just overwrites the continuous path with white background and text (also see the comments in my code below). For more elegant and shorter code, try the [Observable Plot](https://observablehq.com/plot/features/plots) version [mentioned here](https://observablehq.com/@d3/inline-labels#cell-95). The following (unstyled) code should work:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>D3 Stacked Bar and Line Chart</title>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/d3@7"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@observablehq/plot@0.6"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    
<div id="myplot"></div>
<script type="module">
    const sales = [
  { year: "2015", value: 120 },
  { year: "2016", value: 200 },
  { year: "2017", value: 300 },
  { year: "2018", value: 400 },
  { year: "2019", value: 500 }
];


const plot = Plot.plot({
  x: {
    type: "point", // format years without decimal dots and avoid d3 warning
  },
  marks: [
    // plot line
    Plot.line(sales, {x: "year", y: "value", type: "point"}),
    // "paint over" line at number positions
    Plot.dot(sales, {x: "year", y: "value", r: 15, fill: "white"}),
    // put numbers
    Plot.text(sales, {x: "year", y: "value", text: "value"}),
  ],
});

const div = document.querySelector("#myplot");
div.append(plot);

</script>  
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: This solution is okay but my aim is to have multiple line charts and stacked bar charts to gether, and tried using this solution, I was not able to get what I want

Comment: This solution is okay but my aim is to have multiple line charts and stacked bar charts together and tried using this solution, but I was not able to get what I want, if you could provide a sample with stacked bars together I will appreciate it but thanks for the help This solution is okay but my aim is to have multiple line charts and stacked bar charts together and tried using this solution, but I was not able to get what I want, if you could provide a sample with stacked bars together I will appreciate it but thanks for the help

Comment: @TheDeadMan Hm - increasing the scope of the question after getting an accepted answer is ... not the best style. If you now want to have "multiple line charts and stacked bar charts together", please update your question and the expected result accordingly.

Comment: The scope of the question should not be changed. The stacked bar chart part should be a separate question.

Comment: No worries I will accept your answer if there is no any answer which will suit better with what I want. thanks for help though

Comment: @TheDeadMan Well - accepting an answer before the bounty expired apparently didn't work out. Makes me think if I should continue putting effort and time into answering (your) questions :(

Answer (score 2):

To make a background for the data point labels you can copy the text label and make it the same color as the background.

```
   svg.selectAll(".line-text")
   ...
   .call(text => text.clone(true))
   .attr("fill", "none")
   .attr("stroke", "white")
   .attr("stroke-width", "12");
```

As herstrietzel pointed out, you can also put a stroke on the same SVG text element and out te stroke behind the text

```
   svg.selectAll(".line-text")
       ...
  .attr("stroke", "white")
  .attr("stroke-width", "8")
  .attr("stroke-linejoin", "round")
  .attr("paint-order", "stroke")
```

```js
    const data = [
  { year: "2015", value: 120 },
  { year: "2016", value: 200 },
  { year: "2017", value: 300 },
  { year: "2018", value: 400 },
  { year: "2019", value: 500 }
];

const margin = { top: 20, right: 20, bottom: 30, left: 50 };
const width = 600 - margin.left - margin.right;
const height = 400 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

const svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
  .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
  .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
  .append("g")
  .attr("transform", `translate(${margin.left},${margin.top})`);

const xScale = d3.scaleBand()
  .range([0, width])
  .domain(data.map(d => d.year))
  .padding(0.2);

const yScale = d3.scaleLinear()
  .range([height, 0])
  .domain([0, d3.max(data, d => d.value)]);

const line = d3.line()
  .x(d => xScale(d.year) + xScale.bandwidth() / 2)
  .y(d => yScale(d.value))
  .defined(function(d) {return !isNaN(d)});

svg.append("g")
  .attr("transform", `translate(0, ${height})`)
  .call(d3.axisBottom(xScale));

svg.append("g")
  .call(d3.axisLeft(yScale));

  svg.selectAll(".line-segment")
  .data(data.slice(0, -1))
  .enter().append("path")
  .attr("class", "line-segment")
  .attr("d", d => {
    const x1 = xScale(d.year) + xScale.bandwidth() / 2;
    const x2 = xScale(data[data.indexOf(d) + 1].year) + xScale.bandwidth() / 2;
    const y1 = yScale(d.value);
    const y2 = yScale(data[data.indexOf(d) + 1].value);
    return `M${x1},${y1} L${x2},${y2}`;
  })
  .attr("stroke", "steelblue")
  .attr("stroke-width", 2);


svg.selectAll(".line-text")
  .data(data)
  .enter().append("text")
  .attr("class", "line-text")
  .text(d => d.value)
  .attr("x", d => xScale(d.year) + xScale.bandwidth() / 2)
  .attr("y", d => yScale(d.value) - 0)
  .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
  .attr("font-size", "12px")
  .attr("stroke", "white")
  .attr("stroke-width", "8")
  .attr("stroke-linejoin", "round")
  .attr("paint-order", "stroke");
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>D3 Stacked Bar and Line Chart</title>
    <script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v5.min.js"></script>
  </head>
  <style>
    .dot {
  display: none;
}

.line-segment {
  fill: none;
  stroke: steelblue;
  stroke-width: 2;
}

.line-text {
  font-size: 12px;
  font-weight: bold;
}

  </style>
  <body>
    <div id="main-chart">
        <svg width="960" height="500"></svg>
    </div>
    <div id="legends-container">
        <button>Legend</button>
        <svg id="legend" width="960" height="100"></svg>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: looks promising but when I add more data the line is weird can you check your solution here https://codepen.io/LodiLofa/pen/rNqdwLG

Comment: The background padding around the labels works fine in that example. The error with the zig zagging line has nothing to do with my solution but with your path generation. That is a different question.

Comment: You could also apply `"paint-order", "stroke"` to draw the stroke behind the text (no need for clone then). `"stroke-linejoin", "round"` and decreasing the stroke width will also mitigate ugly jagged outline rendering. See [codepen](https://codepen.io/herrstrietzel/pen/MWPVGQZ?editors=0010)

Comment: @herrstrietzel I updated the answer with your recommendation. I was not aware of these attributes. Thanks